# How to analyse .ejs files in Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, ejs

I have an app that uses ejs to render web pages and serve them via express.
I'm using a local instance of sonarqube to analyse the app.
By default the behavior is simply to ignore all .ejs files.

I'd like .ejs files to be analysed.

If this isn't supported I'd at least like to have them be included in the project statistics. I tried adding .ejs as an extension of .html files but it just explodes the number of errors because of missing tags which are rendered at runtime by ejs.

Is there any way to include them in the project cleanly ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think that if SonarQube can't handle the file (doesn't have any plugin that can analyze it), it has no interest in computing any metrics on it.